# Flutter not loading pictures

Tags: flutter, dart, loading

Flutters latest version is not loading pictures in any way so to load the pictures you have to downgrade flutter, and especially the web sdk

you can use flutter downgrade

I tried every possible solution but flutter downgrade is the solution right now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Network Images or Asset Images.

If you are using Network Images add internet permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: network image is working fine, asset image has some sort of problem

Comment: Have you added assets in pubspec.yaml file?